# remote config doesn't re-fetch data at onStart()

Tags: android, firebase-remote-config

I have a **remote-config** variable called **"min_version"** that indicates the minimum version that I wasnt the users to have, if they have a lower version than that - an update alert will pop up. The issue is that when updating remote config on firebase, the information is not available to the app at onStart() and it does not prompt the in-app update feature. ONLY when going to the app setting and pressing "clean data" it will make the information fetching refresh correctly, but no user will do that...

here is my code -

```
@Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // navigation drawer
    checkValidFacebookSession();
    initDrawerMenu();

    // network monitoring
    registerNetworkReceiver();

    // monitoring upload
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mUploadReceiver, new IntentFilter(ULBroadcastConstants.UPLOAD_STATUS_ACTION));
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mFCMReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyFirebaseMessagingService.RECEIVED_FCM_ACTION));

    checkInAppUpdate();

  }

private void checkInAppUpdate() {

    AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(App.getAppContext());
    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo ->  {
      checkUpdateInProgress(appUpdateManager, appUpdateInfo);
      checkUpdateAvailable(appUpdateManager, appUpdateInfo);
    });


  }

  private void checkUpdateInProgress(AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager, AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
      //if an  in app update is already running - resume the update
      try {
        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, this, VERSION_UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE);
      } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }


  private void checkUpdateAvailable(AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager, AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
    getMinAppVersion(() -> {
      int currentVersionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
      if (currentVersionCode < min_version && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
        try {
          appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, this, VERSION_UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }

private void getMinAppVersion(OnRemoteConfigFetchComplete listener){ // <- this is the function that gets the remote config information and fails (returns the last saved variable) without cleaning application data. 
    //fetching the min_version parameter from 'remote config' of Firebase and saves it to our local variable.
    FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(200).build();
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings);
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        min_version = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getLong(RemoteConfigUtil.MIN_VERSION);
        listener.onFetchComplete();
      } else {
        Timber.tag("min version").d("error while fetching and activating remove config");
      }
    });
  }
```